# Sort array of hashes based on value of key in hash?

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I'm attempting to work with Vagrant to perform some automation in spinning up Docker containers. Vagrantfiles are essentially Ruby and thus I should be able to apply Ruby logic to assist with this issue.

I am reading through a conf.d directory filled with YAML files containing configuration data and then pushing a hash of configuration items into an array.  Once done I am itering through the array with .each and applying the configuration to each entry in the array based on the values of some of the keys inside the hash.  One of these keys is "link". The value of link will correlate to the value of another key "name".

I essentially need to ensure that the hash with `link => 'name'` is in the array prior to the hash with `name => 'value'`.

Example of input and expected output:

**Input**

```
containers = [{"name"=>"foo", "ports"=>["80:80", "443:443"], "links"=>["bar", "baz"]}, {"name"=>"bar", "ports"=>["8888:8888"]}, {"name"=>"baz","ports"=>"80:80"}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
containers = [{"name"=>"bar", "ports"=>["8888:8888"]}, {"name"=>"baz", "ports"=>"80:80"}, {"name"=>"foo", "ports"=>["80:80", "443:443"], "links"=>["bar", "baz"]}]
```

The end result is that any entry with "link" appears after an entry in the array where the hash's name key matches it.  (Basically dependency ordering based on the link key.)

Note it may occur that a linked container links to another linked container.

It's been puzzling me a bit as I have the ideas of what I need to do but lack the technical chops to actually figure out "How?" :)

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @john-ledbetter. Forgot to enclose the proper formatting there.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you just provide example input and expected output

Comment: Edited the question to clarify expected input/output. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: I suggest you edit to remove references to Vagrant, Docker and YAML.  They just confuse the question, which (as I understand it) is how to sort an array of hashes to achieve a desired ordering, namely that `g` follow `h` if `h` has a key `"links"` and `h["links"]` includes `g["name"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
def order_containers(containers)
  unordered = containers.dup
  ordered = []
  names_from_ordered = {}
  name_is_ordered = names_from_ordered.method(:[])
  until unordered.empty?
    container = unordered.find do |c|
      c.fetch('links', []).all? &name_is_ordered
    end
    raise 'container ordering impossible' if !container
    ordered << container
    unordered.delete(container)
    names_from_ordered[container.fetch('name')] = true
  end
  ordered
end

containers = [
  { 'name'=>'foo', 'links'=>['bar'] },
  { 'name'=>'a', 'links'=>['goo'] },
  { 'name'=>'bar' },
  { 'name'=>'goo', 'links'=>['foo'] },
]

containers = order_containers(containers)

require 'pp'
pp containers
# => [{"name"=>"bar"},
#     {"name"=>"foo", "links"=>["bar"]},
#     {"name"=>"goo", "links"=>["foo"]},
#     {"name"=>"a", "links"=>["goo"]}]
```

The basic idea is that we use a loop, and each iteration of the loop will find one container from the input list that is suitable for adding to the output list.  A container is suitable for adding to the output list if all the containers it depends on have already been added to the output list.  The container is then removed from the input list and added to the output list.

This loop can terminate in two main ways:

1. when the input list is empty, which would indicate success, or
2. when we cannot find a container that we are able to start, which would be an error caused by a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the simplest thing would be something like:

```
linkless_configs = []
linked_configs = []
if config_hash.has_key?("links")
  linked_configs.push(config_hash)
else
  linkless_configs.push(config_hash)
end
```

then you can iterator over `linkless_configs + linked_configs` and be guaranteed that each linked config comes after the corresponding link-less config.

Alternatively, if you must sort, you could

```
containers.sort_by { |config| config.has_key?("links") ? 1 : 0 }
```

Comment: This is an awesome idea, unfortunately I do need to account for the fact that a linked container may link to another linked container.  I should clarify that in the above question. Sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit:** @DavidGrayson has pointed out a flaw with my answer. I'll see if I can find a fix, but if I cannot, and I fear that may be the case, I'll delete the answer. *[Edit#2*: Oh, my! Someone upvoted my answer after my initial edit. I'm not sure I can delete it now, but to be truthful, I'd already decided not to do so, mainly because my explanation has implications for any proposed solution to the OP's problem. With 10 points in the balance, leaving it up is now even more compelling. *2#tidE]*

I believe I understand the problem. `sort` requires a total order, which is a partial order in which `a <= b` or `a <= b` for every pair of elements. [ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Relation_to_partial_orders) The latter is not a problem, but the partial order requirement is. A partial order must satisfy axioms of:

- reflexivity (`x ≤ x`),
- antisymmetry (if `x ≤ y` and `y ≤ x` then `x = y`) and
- transitivity (if `x ≤ y` and `y ≤ z`, then `x ≤ z`).

My ordering only satisfies the reflexivity axiom. David gives the counter-example:

```
containers = [h0, h1, h2]
```

where

```
h0 = {'name'=>'foo', 'links'=>['bar']},
h1 = {'name'=>'a'},
h2 = {'name'=>'bar'},

containers.sort
  #=> [{"name"=>"foo", "links"=>["bar"]},
  #    {"name"=>"a"}, {"name"=>"bar"}]
```

My method `Hash#<=>` establishes:

```
h0 = h1
h0 > h2
h1 = h2
```

If `sort` were to find that `h0 = h1 = h2`, it would conclude, by transitivity, that `h0 = h2` (and not check `h0 <=> h2`), which may result in an incorrect result.

David also points out that `o.follows?(self)` should raise an exception because I have defined it as `private`.  As I have not yet encountered an exception, I conclude that statement has not been executed, but I have not traced the reason for that, but that's a minor point (though no doubt a useful clue).

I'm grateful to David for identifying the problem.  Incorrect answers need to be exposed, of course, but I feel I've learned something useful  as well.

**tidE]**

If I understand the question correctly, and the data provides a valid ordering, I think you could do it as follows.

```
class Hash
  def <=>(o)
    case
    when   follows?(o)    then  1
    when o.follows?(self) then -1
    else                        0
    end
  end

  private

  def follows?(o)
    key?("links") && self["links"].include?(o["name"])
  end
end

containers = [{"name"=>"foo", "ports"=>["80:80", "443:443"],
               "links"=>["bar", "baz"]},
              {"name"=>"bar", "ports"=>["8888:8888"]},
              {"name"=>"baz","ports"=>"80:80"}]

containers.sort
  #=> [{"name"=>"baz", "ports"=>"80:80"},
  #    {"name"=>"bar", "ports"=>["8888:8888"]},
  #    {"name"=>"foo", "ports"=>["80:80", "443:443"],
  #     "links"=>["bar", "baz"]}]
```

**Addendum**

Although I prefaced with the assumption that the data provides a valid ordering, @Ajedi32 asks what happens when there is a circular reference.  Let's find out:

```
containers = [{"name"=>"foo", "links"=>["bar"]},
              {"name"=>"bar", "links"=>["baz"]},
              {"name"=>"baz", "links"=>["foo"]}]
containers.sort
  #=> [{ "name"=>"baz", "links"=>["foo"] },
  #    { "name"=>"bar", "links"=>["baz"] },
  #    { "name"=>"foo", "links"=>["bar"] }]

containers = [{"name"=>"foo", "links"=>["bar"]},
              {"name"=>"bar", "links"=>["foo"]}]
containers.sort
  #=> [{ "name"=>"bar", "links"=>["foo"] },
  #    { "name"=>"foo", "links"=>["bar"] }]
```

This shows that if one were not certain that there were no circular references, one should check for that before sorting.

Comment: Please don't monkey patch core classes with domain-specific logic just so you can sort your array.

Comment: @Ajedi32, adding `<=>` to `Hash` is not so bad, as `Hash` does not implement that method. (It does inherit that method from `Module`, but it always returns `nil` when comparing hashes.)  I did it this way to simplify the explanation, but I do agree with you that it is not good practice to mess with core classes.  As I'm sure you know, we could create a class for the elements of the array and define `<=>` for that class, or use [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) with Ruby 2.1+.

Comment: Cary, since `follows?` is private, you should get an error at this point:  `o.follows?(self)`.

Comment: Your spaceship operator is very different from normal spaceship operators so I don't think the sort algorithm is guaranteed to give the right results.  Here is an example where it gives a bad result: https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/3ece486a516e142a113d

Comment: @Ajedi32, you might be interested in David's comments and my edit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah yes. I did think about that, but for some reason I assumed it would only be a problem in the case of circular dependencies. Intuitively, I figured a spaceship operator for which `x <= y` and `y <= z` does not imply `x <= z` might be a problem, but I wasn't certain as to why.